# why is it that when I pass an array as a parameter for a function, its values are changing?

Tags: arrays, c, function, parameters

the function is supposed to receive: a sorted array of integers, a starting index, an end index, and an integer number, and return the amount of values in the array between the start and end indexes that are smaller than the number.

when I pass an array into the function, {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,10} for example, as soon as the function is called, the array changes to an array with a random single value.

can anyone tell me why that is happening and how do I fix it?

this is the code:

```
int countSmaller(int arr[], int start, int end, int num) {
     int mid = start+(end - start) / 2;

 if (arr[end] < num)
     return (end - start) ;
 if (arr[start >= num])
     return 0;
 if (arr[mid] >= num)
     return countSmaller(arr, start, mid,num);
return (mid + 1-start) + countSmaller(arr, mid + 1, end, num);

void main(){
 int arr = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,10};
 countSmaller(arr,0,9,5);

}
```

it's supposed to return 4, but because the array for some reason changes, the return value is incorrect.

Comment: You don't have an array.

Comment: Compiling with warnings on should have given you a hint about this.

Comment: `arr[start >= num]` seems very odd. Would you mind explaining what you think this does?

Comment: This code does not compile.

Comment: Please don't edit to fix the errors in your code. It makes answers not relevant.

Comment: Highly recommended for saving you from trouble-shooting bugs that the compiler has already found: [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)

Answer (score 1):

It is not an array only single integer.

You need to change it to:

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,10};
```

- You need to be much more careful when you program. Your second `if` was also wrong.
- `main` function **has** to return `int` (not `void`)

```
int countSmaller(int arr[], int start, int end, int num) {
    int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;

    if (arr[end] < num)
        return (end - start);
    if (arr[start] >= num)
        return 0;
    if (arr[mid] >= num)
        return countSmaller(arr, start, mid, num);
    return (mid + 1-start) + countSmaller(arr, mid + 1, end, num);
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 10};
    printf("%d\n", countSmaller(arr, 0, 9, 5));
}
```

Comment: You might also point out that `void main() { ... }` should probably be `int main(void) { ... }`

Comment: @Chris indeed - missed that

Comment: @gulpr I have not understood what the difference is between the declaration of the array in the question int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,10}; and your declaration of the array in the answer int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,10};.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow OP just had `int arr = { /* ... */ };`. Got changed in an edit.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow you should check  **edits** before commenting. It was obvious that the question was modified

Comment: @gulpr What does this have to do with me? I didn't edit the question, did I?

Comment: @Joel sorry - not you indeed.

Comment: If you see the OP changing the code like that to "fix" the bugs pointed out by answers, do an edit rollback if you have edit privileges, or otherwise flag for moderator attention explaining why the edit is invalid.